# Trigger to change all the rows after an update is done

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

Having a table with the name `transitions`, **I want to change the values of all the rows** after any update is made.

I'm using the following trigger, which changes only the ROW that I'm making the update to.

```
CREATE TRIGGER signaturetrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON `transactions` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET New.signature = '288';
END
```

I'm trying to change all the rows to `signature = 288`, how can I modify the trigger in order to archieve that? I thought that using `FOR EACH ROW` would be enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cant update same table using its on trigger (you can only change that new raw but not the entire table )

Comment: You are doing something very wrong if you want to update every row in the table when updating a single row.

Comment: _I'm trying to change all the rows to_ you mean all rows in table? or all rows involved?

Comment: All rows of the table `transactions`.

Comment: that is very wrong design. I would suggest to create new table `release` or `transaction version` or `whatever_table` with auto_increment `id`  and insert new line into that table every time.

Comment: It's not about db design it's about some basics I want to learn. This is just an example, not a real implementation.

Comment: It's not something you should do. Think about it: what happens to all the rows you subsequently update. Should they all run the same trigger again?

Comment: if it is just for learning, drop it, and set some another good goal

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *after* update trigger with an `update` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER signaturetrigger AFTER UPDATE ON `transactions`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE transactions
        SET New.signature = '288';
END;
```

This does seem like a very strange thing to do, however.

Consider an alternative:  just add an `UpdatedAt` column into the table and update the signature in that row.  Then, when you want the most recent signature use:

```
select signature
from transactions
order by UpdatedAt desc
limit 1;
```

An index on `transactions(UpdatedAt, signature)` will make this quite speedy.  And, the update will go much, much faster than updating all rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the update seems quite logic, but I'm having the following error `Can't update table 'transactions' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`

Comment: @Borja . . . Is that true even for an *after* update trigger?  In any event, you can follow the advice in the second half of the answer.